# Creating a dummy account for account verification

Tags: account-security

I recently wanted to do some major changes to my account for an online game. So they wanted to do a thorough account verification.

First they asked me for some character information which can be easily gotten from the account as well as where the account was created. This seems like a great question because you can't see that information when logging into the account.

Then they asked for my current IP address (using a third party site like whatsmyip) and then asked me to create a dummy account. Creating a dummy account only requires an account name and an email address, you don't even need access to the email address.

Question: what is the point of creating a dummy account? What information helpful for account verification to they gain from that?

PS: I'm certain I talked to the actual support of the online game as the changes to my account where made and this could not have been done by a thirty party hacker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the goal is to compare your current ip when you create this dummy account with the one you use for your real account.

However, this system does not seem practical for a user. Normally a confirmation of the current password, a code or a link sent by email is enough.

Comment: The current IP address I gave them during the process and the one use for creating the dummy account should be the same, but I don't see how that provides any information to them. My IP address at account creation is almost certainly different, as I changed hardware and internet provider since then, moved to different city and AFAIK currently have dynamic IP addresses.

Comment: That's why it would seem odd to me that they do it but it's still likely. If the last IP used with your real account is the same as the one you use to request to modify your information, this gives them a clue to consider the action as legitimate. If they had been different, they might have asked you something else.